Problem with wrapping a TIKZ figure using wrap figure and also with \input{insbox.tex}
I have tried using wrap figure to embed some tikz figure and it was just a no go. Then I tried to use the Insertbox command and it worked but it creates an empty box in the next page of my document. I have no idea of how to fix it, please give me some help.
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart} % for a short document
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-2in}
\calclayout
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage[altbullet]{lucidabr}

\usepackage{setspace} 
%\onehalfspacing
%\OnehalfSpacing*
%\usepackage{layout}
%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{euler}
%\usepackage[bitstream-charter, greekfamily=bodoni]{mathdesign}
% See the ``Memoir customise'' template for some common customisations
% Don't forget to read the Memoir manual: memman.pdf
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usepackage[mathcal]{eucal}
%\newcommand{\mathfrak}{\EuFrak}
%\DeclareMathAlphabet\EuFrak{U}{euf}{m}{n} \SetMathAlphabet\EuFrak{bold}{U}{euf}{b}{n}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=5,minbibnames=4,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\input{insbox.tex}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\AtBeginEnvironment{example}{%
  \pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\square$}%
}
\AtEndEnvironment{example}{\popQED\endexample}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
%\usepackage{showlabels}
%\usepackage{MnSymbol}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\fus}{\circledast}
\newcommand{\fus}{%
  \mathop{\scalebox{1.5}{\raisebox{-0.2ex}{$\circledast$}}
  }
}
\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA10
  <12-> MnSymbolA12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolA-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyA} {U} {MnSymbolA}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lcirclearrowright}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{252}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rcirclearrowleft}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{250}

\DeclareMathOperator\ad{ad}
\DeclareMathOperator\Ad{Ad}
\DeclareMathOperator\aut{Aut}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Lie}{Lie}
\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}

\newcommand{\g}{\mathfrak{g}}
\newcommand{\h}{\mathfrak{h}}

\newcommand{\rank} 
{\operatornamewithlimits{rank}}
\newcommand{\traza} 
{\operatornamewithlimits{Tr}}
\newcommand{\matriz} 
{\operatornamewithlimits{Mat}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calligraphy}
\tikzset{
  % style to apply some styles to each segment of a path
  on each segment/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      moveto code={},
      lineto code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      curveto code={
        \path [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
        .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..
        (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      closepath code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
    },
  },
  % style to add an arrow in the middle of a path
  mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[#1]{Stealth[scale width=1.5]}}
      }}},
}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{todonotes}
%\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
%\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}
%\usepackage{miestilo}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
    
\title{Notes on GK}
%\author{}\address{}
%\email{}

\date{} % Delete this line to display the current date
%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
%\layout

\begin{abstract} 
\end{abstract}\maketitle
\tableofcontents % the asterisk means that the contents itself isn't put into the ToC


 
\begin{proposition}\label{pro:doumorequ} Let $(\Sigma_1,V_1)$ be the square (disc with four marked points) and let $(\Sigma_0,V_0)$ be the disc with two marked points. Then the following statements hold.
\begin{enumerate} \item The maps indicated in the diagram below constitute source and target maps for a double groupoid structure \[\begin{tikzcd}
{\hom(\Pi_1(\Sigma,V),G)} \arrow[dd, "{[g_i,k_i]\mapsto [k_1,g_2,k_2]}"', shift right] \arrow[dd, "{[g_i,k_i]\mapsto [k_4,g_4,k_3]}", shift left] \arrow[rr, "{[g_i,k_i]\mapsto [k_4,g_1,k_1]}", shift left] \arrow[rr, "{[g_i,k_i]\mapsto [k_3,g_3,k_2]}"', shift right] &  & {\hom(\Pi_1(\Sigma_1,V_1),G)} \arrow[dd, "{[x,g,y]\mapsto y}"', shift right] \arrow[dd, "{[x,g,y]\mapsto x}", shift left] \\
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          &  &                                                                                                                           \\
{\hom(\Pi_1(\Sigma_1,V_1),G)} \arrow[rr, "{[x,g,y]\mapsto y}"', shift right] \arrow[rr, "{[x,g,y]\mapsto x}", shift left]                                                                                                                                                 &  & {\hom(\Pi_1(\Sigma_0,V_0),G)}                                                                                            
\end{tikzcd} \] 
with the generators displayed in Figure \ref{fig:doucomlie}. 
\item When restricted to the decorations described in \eqref{eq:dec}, the structure maps of the above double groupoid structure descend to a symplectic $(1,1)$ morphism relating the corresponding moduli spaces as in \eqref{eq:doumormodspa}. \end{enumerate} 
\end{proposition}  
\begin{proof} The groupoid structure on $\hom(\Pi_1(\Sigma_1,V_1),G) \rightrightarrows \hom(\Pi_1(\Sigma_0,V_0),G)$ is given by the multiplication $(x,g,y)\circ (y,h,z)=(x,gh,z)$ (so it is the product of the pair groupoid over $G$ and $G \rightrightarrows \{*\}$). The double groupoid structure of item (1) is simply the (generalized) Lu-Weinstein double groupoid corresponding to both side groupoids being equal to $\hom(\Pi_1(\Sigma_1,V_1),G) \rightrightarrows \hom(\Pi_1(\Sigma_0,V_0),G)$. 

The claim in item (2) follows from considering the trivial $(1,1)$ morphism induced by the double groupoid structure of the item above and then by observing that all the corresponding Morita equivalences descend to the subquotients. This is a straightforward verification so we will only analyse the last column in \eqref{eq:doumormodspa}, the other examples are analogous. Here the holomorphic Poisson groupoids are the following: the first one, denoted by $\mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{A}_-}$, is the quotient of the action groupoid 
\[ (G_+ \times G_-) \ltimes G \rightrightarrows G, \quad (u,x)\cdot g \mapsto ugx^{-1}, \quad \forall (u,x,g)\in( G_+ \times G_- )\ltimes G \]
by the left action of $G_-^2$ determined by $  (y,z)\cdot(u,x,g) =(u,yxz^{-1},gz^{-1})$ for all $(y,z)\in G_-^2$ and all $(u,x,g)\in (G_+ \times G_-) \ltimes G$. One can easily check that the quotient of such an action is the action groupoid $G_+ \ltimes (G/G_-) \rightrightarrows G/G_-$. On the other hand, we have $\mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{B}_- }$ which is the quotient of the action groupoid
\[ (G_- \times G_-) \ltimes G \rightrightarrows G, \quad (x,y)\cdot g \mapsto xgy^{-1}, \quad \forall (x,y,g)\in (G_- \times G_- )\ltimes G \]
by the left $G_-^2$-action $(z_1,z_2)\cdot (x,y,g)=(x,z_1yz_2^{-1},gz_2^{-1})$ for all $(z_1,z_2)\in G_-^2$ and all $(x,y,g)\in (G_- \times G_-) \ltimes G$. This quotient is the action groupoid $G_- \ltimes(G/G_-)\rightrightarrows G/G_-$. So the Lu-Weinstein construction gives us a holomorphic double groupoid 
\[ \begin{tikzcd}
{D_-} \arrow[r, shift right] \arrow[r, shift left] \arrow[d, shift right] \arrow[d, shift left] & \mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{A}_-} \arrow[d, shift right] \arrow[d, shift left] \\
\mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{B}_-} \arrow[r, shift right] \arrow[r, shift left]                                                                 & G/G_-;                                                     
\end{tikzcd}\]
the symplectic structure on $D_-$ comes from the identification $D_- \rightarrow \mathfrak{M}_{L_{D_-}}$ which is given as follows. An element $\rho\in D_-$ as below 
\[ \rho=\left((u',ygG_-),(y,gG_-),(y',ugG_-),(u,gG_-)\right)\in \mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{A}_- } \times_{G/G_-} \mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{B}_- } \times \mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{B}_- } \times_{G/G_-} \mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{A}_-}    \]
satisfies that $y'ug=u'ygz^{-1}$ for a unique $z\in G_-$. So we can identify $\rho$ with the representation whose values on the generators of $\Pi_1(\Sigma,V)$ indicated in Figure \ref{fig:doucomlie} are displayed in the following diagram: 
\InsertBoxR{0}{\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=stealth,x=1cm,y=1cm, scale=0.55]
    \clip(-2.171814835019457,6.22534829668545) rectangle (9.0,15.23302026597934);
  \coordinate (a) at (0,7);
 \coordinate (b) at (7,14);
 \coordinate (c) at (2,9);
 \coordinate (d) at (5,12);
   \draw[fill=black!10] (a) rectangle (b);
   \draw[fill=white] (c) rectangle (d);
                \draw [line width=1pt, <-] (0,7)-- (7,7);
                \draw [line width=1pt, ->] (7,7)-- (7,14);
                \draw [line width=1pt,->] (7,14)-- (0,14);
                \draw [line width=1pt, <-] (0,14)-- (0,7);
                \draw [line width=1pt,<-] (2,9)-- (5,9);
                \draw [line width=1pt,->] (5,9)-- (5,12);
                \draw [line width=1pt,->] (5,12)-- (2,12);
                \draw [line width=1pt,<-] (2,12)-- (2,9);
                \draw [dashed,line width=1pt,<-] (5,12)-- (7,14);
                \draw [dashed,line width=1pt,->] (7,7)-- (5,9);
                \draw [dashed,line width=1pt,->] (0,7)-- (2,9);
                \draw [dashed,line width=1pt,->] (0,14)-- (2,12);
                \begin{scriptsize}
                    \draw [fill=black] (0,7) circle (1.7pt);
                    %\draw[color=black] (0.13963706202407788,6.868854865513323) node {$N_1$};
                    \draw [fill=black] (7,7) circle (1.7pt);
                    %\draw[color=black] (7.129122246927775,7.296533154799387) node {$Q_1$};
                    \draw[color=black] (3.548843996618713,6.654390523370536) node {$z\in G_-$};
                    \draw [fill=black] (7,14) circle (1.7pt);
                    %\draw[color=black] (7.129122246927775,14.298237719396944) node {$T_1$};
                    \draw[color=black] (7.96,10.64464319092457) node {$1\in G_-$};
                    \draw [fill=black] (0,14) circle (1.7pt);
                    %\draw[color=black] (0.13963706202407788,14.298237719396944) node {$U_1$};
                    \draw[color=black] (3.548843996618713,14.347115238172494) node {$1\in G_-$};
                    \draw[color=black] (-0.89,10.64464319092457) node {$1\in G_-$};
                    \draw [fill=black] (2,9) circle (1.7pt);
                    %\draw[color=black] (2.131395952127754,9.300511424596943) node {$W_1$};
                    \draw [fill=black] (5,9) circle (1.7pt);
                    %\draw[color=black] (5.137363356824099,9.300511424596943) node {$Z_1$};
                    \draw[color=black] (3.548843996618713,8.6) node {$y\in G_-$};
                    \draw [fill=black] (5,12) circle (1.7pt);                   \draw[color=black] (6.0,10.64464319092457) node {$u\in G_+$};
                    \draw [fill=black] (2,12) circle (1.7pt);
                    \draw[color=black] (3.548843996618713,12.343136968374939) node {$y'\in G_-$};
                    \draw[color=black] (1.1,10.64464319092457) node {$u'\in G_+$};
                    \draw[color=black] (6.3,12.5) node {$ug$};
                    \draw[color=black] (6.1760106308045435,8.286302910004277) node {$g$};
                    \draw[color=black] (1.9,8.00) node {$ygz^{-1}$};
                    \draw[color=black] (0.9094579827389956,12.5) node {$g'$};
                \end{scriptsize}    
\end{tikzpicture}}[0] where $g'=y'ug=u'ygz^{-1}$. By definition, the symplectic form on $D_-$ coincides with the pullback of \eqref{eq:luweicomlie} by the identification above, it is straightforward to verify it is doubly multiplicative. 

The same considerations applied to $\mathfrak{M}_{L_{D_{+}}}$ give us now a holomorphic symplectic double groupoid $D_+$ whose side groupoids are the action groupoids $\mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{A}_+ }=((G_+\backslash G) \rtimes G_- \rightrightarrows G_+\backslash G)$ and $\mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{B}_+ }=((G_+\backslash G) \rtimes G_+ \rightrightarrows G_+\backslash G)$ corresponding to the right actions, respectively, of $G_-$ and $G_+$ on the quotient by left translations $G_+\backslash G$. Now we will describe the Morita equivalence between $D_+$ and $D_-$ determined by $\mathfrak{M}_{L_{Z}}$. The holomorphic biprincipal bibundle relating $\mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{A}_+ }$ and $\mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{A}_- }$ is the quotient $Z$ of $G_+ \times G_- \times G$ by the left $G_+ \times G_-$-action
\[ (u,x)\cdot (v,y,g) =(uv,yx^{-1},gx^{-1}), \quad \forall (u,x)\in G_+ \times G_-, \,  (v,y,g)\in G_+ \times G_- \times G, \]
So we have that $Z$ is identifed with $G$ and the two commuting actions that define the Morita equivalence are simply given by left and right translation
\begin{equation} \begin{tikzcd}
(G_+\backslash G) \rtimes G_- \arrow[d, shift right] \arrow[d, shift left] \arrow[r, dotted, bend left=49] & Z\cong G \arrow[ld, "p_+"'] \arrow[rd, "p_-"] & G_+ \ltimes(G/G_-)\arrow[d, shift left] \arrow[d, shift right] \arrow[l, dotted, bend right=49] & {p_+(g)=G_+g} &   {p_-(g)=gG_-;} \\
G_+\backslash G                                                                                 &                                        & G/G_-                                                                                            &                           &  &                   
\end{tikzcd}\end{equation} 
the actions $((G_+\backslash G) \rtimes G_- ) \times_{G_+\backslash G} G \rightarrow G$ and $G \times_{G/G_-}( G_+ \ltimes (G/G_-) )\rightarrow G$ are given, respectively, by the maps
\begin{align*} &((G_+y,b),g)\mapsto gb^{-1},\quad \forall ((G_+y,b),g) \in ((G_+\backslash G) \rtimes G_- ) \times_{G_+\backslash G} G \\
& (g,(a,xG_-)) \mapsto a^{-1}g, \quad \forall (g,(a,xG_-))\in G \times_{G/G_-}( G_+ \ltimes G/G_- ). 
\end{align*} 
By considering an analogous diagram to \eqref{eq:idmodspa} we get an identification 
\[\mathfrak{M}_{L_{Z_{0}}} \rightarrow  Z \times_{G/G_-} \mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{B}_-} \times \mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{B}_+} \times_{G_+\backslash G} Z \]
that induces a suitable symplectic form on $Z \times_{G/G_-} \mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{B}_-} \times \mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{B}_+} \times_{G_+\backslash G} Z$. We can proceed similarly to describe explicitly all the Morita equivalences in \eqref{eq:doumormodspa}. \end{proof}
\begin{remark} For future reference, let us point out that the Morita equivalence corresponding to $\mathfrak{M}_{L_{W}}(G)$ is, at the level of side groupoids, as follows: 
\begin{equation} \begin{tikzcd}
G_+ \ltimes (G/G_+) \arrow[d, shift right] \arrow[d, shift left] \arrow[r, dotted, bend left=49] & W\cong G \arrow[ld, "q_-"'] \arrow[rd, "q_+"] & (G_+\backslash G )\rtimes G_+\arrow[d, shift left] \arrow[d, shift right] \arrow[l, dotted, bend right=49] & {q_+(g)=G_+g} &   {q_-(g)=gG_+;} \\
 G/G_+                                                                                 &                                        & G_+\backslash G                                                                                            &                           &  &                   
\end{tikzcd}\end{equation}
with the actions given by left and right multiplication by $G_+$.
\end{remark}% moved
\printbibliography
\end{document}


First, include a document class.  Then throw out everything not related to the problem.  If the problem goes away, you may have found the solution.

Welcome! \calclayout is not a LaTeX command. Presumably some non-standard class or package you've not included defines it.

@cfr -- \calclayout is the mechanism used in AMS document classes to set up the page geometry.  (The class used does need to be specified.)  But this is never going to work with \end{remark} coming after \end{document}.

@JohnKormylo the OP had a documentclass just markdown error (backticks not on their own line) meant it did not show

Your example is far from minimal but it produces this output once I moved \end{remark} (or if you ignored teh error that it was missing, as that final remark environment is unrelated to the question , wrapfig would also work here.  What error did you get?

Thank you for your comments, indeed I was able to fix the problem by introducing a space between end of theorem and remark. However, I would like to use wrapfig as well but when I use that, the figure is just not present in the pdf. Maybe there is an issue with the equations in display mode.

@DavidCarlisle proof isn't defined as a list?

@cfr usually is yes, but that's not a complete block for wrapfig if you are careful (normally)

@DavidCarlisle It isn't? What does 'careful' amount to here?

@cfr  wrap it in a minipage for example, see answer.

The posted code works without error in texlive 2024 producing

To use wrapfigure inside a proof you need to guard it in a minipage (actually that's probably not strictly necessary, but is the easiest way to make things safe for wrapfigure)
It then produces

In both cases you have a paragraph starting where... I would move that sentence earlier to finish the sentence that currently ends with following diagram:
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart} % for a short document
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-2in}
\calclayout
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage[altbullet]{lucidabr}

\usepackage{setspace} 
%\onehalfspacing
%\OnehalfSpacing*
%\usepackage{layout}
%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{euler}
%\usepackage[bitstream-charter, greekfamily=bodoni]{mathdesign}
% See the ``Memoir customise'' template for some common customisations
% Don't forget to read the Memoir manual: memman.pdf
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usepackage[mathcal]{eucal}
%\newcommand{\mathfrak}{\EuFrak}
%\DeclareMathAlphabet\EuFrak{U}{euf}{m}{n} \SetMathAlphabet\EuFrak{bold}{U}{euf}{b}{n}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=5,minbibnames=4,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\input{insbox.tex}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\AtBeginEnvironment{example}{%
  \pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\square$}%
}
\AtEndEnvironment{example}{\popQED\endexample}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
%\usepackage{showlabels}
%\usepackage{MnSymbol}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\fus}{\circledast}
\newcommand{\fus}{%
  \mathop{\scalebox{1.5}{\raisebox{-0.2ex}{$\circledast$}}
  }
}
\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA10
  <12-> MnSymbolA12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolA-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyA} {U} {MnSymbolA}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lcirclearrowright}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{252}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rcirclearrowleft}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{250}

\DeclareMathOperator\ad{ad}
\DeclareMathOperator\Ad{Ad}
\DeclareMathOperator\aut{Aut}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Lie}{Lie}
\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}

\newcommand{\g}{\mathfrak{g}}
\newcommand{\h}{\mathfrak{h}}

\newcommand{\rank} 
{\operatornamewithlimits{rank}}
\newcommand{\traza} 
{\operatornamewithlimits{Tr}}
\newcommand{\matriz} 
{\operatornamewithlimits{Mat}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calligraphy}
\tikzset{
  % style to apply some styles to each segment of a path
  on each segment/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      moveto code={},
      lineto code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      curveto code={
        \path [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
        .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..
        (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      closepath code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
    },
  },
  % style to add an arrow in the middle of a path
  mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[#1]{Stealth[scale width=1.5]}}
      }}},
}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{todonotes}
%\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
%\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}
%\usepackage{miestilo}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
    
\title{Notes on GK}
%\author{}\address{}
%\email{}

\date{} % Delete this line to display the current date
%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
%\layout

\begin{abstract} 
\end{abstract}\maketitle
\tableofcontents % the asterisk means that the contents itself isn't put into the ToC


 
\begin{proposition}\label{pro:doumorequ} Let $(\Sigma_1,V_1)$ be the square (disc with four marked points) and let $(\Sigma_0,V_0)$ be the disc with two marked points. Then the following statements hold.
\begin{enumerate} \item The maps indicated in the diagram below constitute source and target maps for a double groupoid structure \[\begin{tikzcd}
{\hom(\Pi_1(\Sigma,V),G)} \arrow[dd, "{[g_i,k_i]\mapsto [k_1,g_2,k_2]}"', shift right] \arrow[dd, "{[g_i,k_i]\mapsto [k_4,g_4,k_3]}", shift left] \arrow[rr, "{[g_i,k_i]\mapsto [k_4,g_1,k_1]}", shift left] \arrow[rr, "{[g_i,k_i]\mapsto [k_3,g_3,k_2]}"', shift right] &  & {\hom(\Pi_1(\Sigma_1,V_1),G)} \arrow[dd, "{[x,g,y]\mapsto y}"', shift right] \arrow[dd, "{[x,g,y]\mapsto x}", shift left] \\
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          &  &                                                                                                                           \\
{\hom(\Pi_1(\Sigma_1,V_1),G)} \arrow[rr, "{[x,g,y]\mapsto y}"', shift right] \arrow[rr, "{[x,g,y]\mapsto x}", shift left]                                                                                                                                                 &  & {\hom(\Pi_1(\Sigma_0,V_0),G)}                                                                                            
\end{tikzcd} \] 
with the generators displayed in Figure \ref{fig:doucomlie}. 
\item When restricted to the decorations described in \eqref{eq:dec}, the structure maps of the above double groupoid structure descend to a symplectic $(1,1)$ morphism relating the corresponding moduli spaces as in \eqref{eq:doumormodspa}. \end{enumerate} 
\end{proposition}  
\begin{proof} The groupoid structure on $\hom(\Pi_1(\Sigma_1,V_1),G) \rightrightarrows \hom(\Pi_1(\Sigma_0,V_0),G)$ is given by the multiplication $(x,g,y)\circ (y,h,z)=(x,gh,z)$ (so it is the product of the pair groupoid over $G$ and $G \rightrightarrows \{*\}$). The double groupoid structure of item (1) is simply the (generalized) Lu-Weinstein double groupoid corresponding to both side groupoids being equal to $\hom(\Pi_1(\Sigma_1,V_1),G) \rightrightarrows \hom(\Pi_1(\Sigma_0,V_0),G)$. 

The claim in item (2) follows from considering the trivial $(1,1)$ morphism induced by the double groupoid structure of the item above and then by observing that all the corresponding Morita equivalences descend to the subquotients. This is a straightforward verification so we will only analyse the last column in \eqref{eq:doumormodspa}, the other examples are analogous. Here the holomorphic Poisson groupoids are the following: the first one, denoted by $\mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{A}_-}$, is the quotient of the action groupoid 
\[ (G_+ \times G_-) \ltimes G \rightrightarrows G, \quad (u,x)\cdot g \mapsto ugx^{-1}, \quad \forall (u,x,g)\in( G_+ \times G_- )\ltimes G \]
by the left action of $G_-^2$ determined by $  (y,z)\cdot(u,x,g) =(u,yxz^{-1},gz^{-1})$ for all $(y,z)\in G_-^2$ and all $(u,x,g)\in (G_+ \times G_-) \ltimes G$. One can easily check that the quotient of such an action is the action groupoid $G_+ \ltimes (G/G_-) \rightrightarrows G/G_-$. On the other hand, we have $\mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{B}_- }$ which is the quotient of the action groupoid
\[ (G_- \times G_-) \ltimes G \rightrightarrows G, \quad (x,y)\cdot g \mapsto xgy^{-1}, \quad \forall (x,y,g)\in (G_- \times G_- )\ltimes G \]
by the left $G_-^2$-action $(z_1,z_2)\cdot (x,y,g)=(x,z_1yz_2^{-1},gz_2^{-1})$ for all $(z_1,z_2)\in G_-^2$ and all $(x,y,g)\in (G_- \times G_-) \ltimes G$. This quotient is the action groupoid $G_- \ltimes(G/G_-)\rightrightarrows G/G_-$. So the Lu-Weinstein construction gives us a holomorphic double groupoid 
\[ \begin{tikzcd}
{D_-} \arrow[r, shift right] \arrow[r, shift left] \arrow[d, shift right] \arrow[d, shift left] & \mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{A}_-} \arrow[d, shift right] \arrow[d, shift left] \\
\mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{B}_-} \arrow[r, shift right] \arrow[r, shift left]                                                                 & G/G_-;                                                     
\end{tikzcd}\]
the symplectic structure on $D_-$ comes from the identification $D_- \rightarrow \mathfrak{M}_{L_{D_-}}$ which is given as follows. An element $\rho\in D_-$ as below 
\[ \rho=\left((u',ygG_-),(y,gG_-),(y',ugG_-),(u,gG_-)\right)\in \mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{A}_- } \times_{G/G_-} \mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{B}_- } \times \mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{B}_- } \times_{G/G_-} \mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{A}_-}    \]
satisfies that $y'ug=u'ygz^{-1}$ for a unique $z\in G_-$. So we can identify $\rho$ with the representation whose values on the generators of $\Pi_1(\Sigma,V)$ indicated in Figure \ref{fig:doucomlie} are displayed in the following diagram: 

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=stealth,x=1cm,y=1cm, scale=0.55]
    \clip(-2.171814835019457,6.22534829668545) rectangle (9.0,15.23302026597934);
  \coordinate (a) at (0,7);
 \coordinate (b) at (7,14);
 \coordinate (c) at (2,9);
 \coordinate (d) at (5,12);
   \draw[fill=black!10] (a) rectangle (b);
   \draw[fill=white] (c) rectangle (d);
                \draw [line width=1pt, <-] (0,7)-- (7,7);
                \draw [line width=1pt, ->] (7,7)-- (7,14);
                \draw [line width=1pt,->] (7,14)-- (0,14);
                \draw [line width=1pt, <-] (0,14)-- (0,7);
                \draw [line width=1pt,<-] (2,9)-- (5,9);
                \draw [line width=1pt,->] (5,9)-- (5,12);
                \draw [line width=1pt,->] (5,12)-- (2,12);
                \draw [line width=1pt,<-] (2,12)-- (2,9);
                \draw [dashed,line width=1pt,<-] (5,12)-- (7,14);
                \draw [dashed,line width=1pt,->] (7,7)-- (5,9);
                \draw [dashed,line width=1pt,->] (0,7)-- (2,9);
                \draw [dashed,line width=1pt,->] (0,14)-- (2,12);
                \begin{scriptsize}
                    \draw [fill=black] (0,7) circle (1.7pt);
                    %\draw[color=black] (0.13963706202407788,6.868854865513323) node {$N_1$};
                    \draw [fill=black] (7,7) circle (1.7pt);
                    %\draw[color=black] (7.129122246927775,7.296533154799387) node {$Q_1$};
                    \draw[color=black] (3.548843996618713,6.654390523370536) node {$z\in G_-$};
                    \draw [fill=black] (7,14) circle (1.7pt);
                    %\draw[color=black] (7.129122246927775,14.298237719396944) node {$T_1$};
                    \draw[color=black] (7.96,10.64464319092457) node {$1\in G_-$};
                    \draw [fill=black] (0,14) circle (1.7pt);
                    %\draw[color=black] (0.13963706202407788,14.298237719396944) node {$U_1$};
                    \draw[color=black] (3.548843996618713,14.347115238172494) node {$1\in G_-$};
                    \draw[color=black] (-0.89,10.64464319092457) node {$1\in G_-$};
                    \draw [fill=black] (2,9) circle (1.7pt);
                    %\draw[color=black] (2.131395952127754,9.300511424596943) node {$W_1$};
                    \draw [fill=black] (5,9) circle (1.7pt);
                    %\draw[color=black] (5.137363356824099,9.300511424596943) node {$Z_1$};
                    \draw[color=black] (3.548843996618713,8.6) node {$y\in G_-$};
                    \draw [fill=black] (5,12) circle (1.7pt);                   \draw[color=black] (6.0,10.64464319092457) node {$u\in G_+$};
                    \draw [fill=black] (2,12) circle (1.7pt);
                    \draw[color=black] (3.548843996618713,12.343136968374939) node {$y'\in G_-$};
                    \draw[color=black] (1.1,10.64464319092457) node {$u'\in G_+$};
                    \draw[color=black] (6.3,12.5) node {$ug$};
                    \draw[color=black] (6.1760106308045435,8.286302910004277) node {$g$};
                    \draw[color=black] (1.9,8.00) node {$ygz^{-1}$};
                    \draw[color=black] (0.9094579827389956,12.5) node {$g'$};
                \end{scriptsize}    
              \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{wrapfigure}

            where $g'=y'ug=u'ygz^{-1}$. By definition, the symplectic form on $D_-$ coincides with the pullback of \eqref{eq:luweicomlie} by the identification above, it is straightforward to verify it is doubly multiplicative. 

The same considerations applied to $\mathfrak{M}_{L_{D_{+}}}$ give us now a holomorphic symplectic double groupoid $D_+$ whose side groupoids are the action groupoids $\mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{A}_+ }=((G_+\backslash G) \rtimes G_- \rightrightarrows G_+\backslash G)$ and $\mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{B}_+ }=((G_+\backslash G) \rtimes G_+ \rightrightarrows G_+\backslash G)$ corresponding to the right actions, respectively, of $G_-$ and $G_+$ on the quotient by left translations $G_+\backslash G$. Now we will describe the Morita equivalence between $D_+$ and $D_-$ determined by $\mathfrak{M}_{L_{Z}}$. The holomorphic biprincipal bibundle relating $\mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{A}_+ }$ and $\mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{A}_- }$ is the quotient $Z$ of $G_+ \times G_- \times G$ by the left $G_+ \times G_-$-action
\[ (u,x)\cdot (v,y,g) =(uv,yx^{-1},gx^{-1}), \quad \forall (u,x)\in G_+ \times G_-, \,  (v,y,g)\in G_+ \times G_- \times G, \]
So we have that $Z$ is identifed with $G$ and the two commuting actions that define the Morita equivalence are simply given by left and right translation
\end{minipage}
\begin{equation} \begin{tikzcd}
(G_+\backslash G) \rtimes G_- \arrow[d, shift right] \arrow[d, shift left] \arrow[r, dotted, bend left=49] & Z\cong G \arrow[ld, "p_+"'] \arrow[rd, "p_-"] & G_+ \ltimes(G/G_-)\arrow[d, shift left] \arrow[d, shift right] \arrow[l, dotted, bend right=49] & {p_+(g)=G_+g} &   {p_-(g)=gG_-;} \\
G_+\backslash G                                                                                 &                                        & G/G_-                                                                                            &                           &  &                   
\end{tikzcd}\end{equation} 
the actions $((G_+\backslash G) \rtimes G_- ) \times_{G_+\backslash G} G \rightarrow G$ and $G \times_{G/G_-}( G_+ \ltimes (G/G_-) )\rightarrow G$ are given, respectively, by the maps
\begin{align*} &((G_+y,b),g)\mapsto gb^{-1},\quad \forall ((G_+y,b),g) \in ((G_+\backslash G) \rtimes G_- ) \times_{G_+\backslash G} G \\
& (g,(a,xG_-)) \mapsto a^{-1}g, \quad \forall (g,(a,xG_-))\in G \times_{G/G_-}( G_+ \ltimes G/G_- ). 
\end{align*} 
By considering an analogous diagram to \eqref{eq:idmodspa} we get an identification 
\[\mathfrak{M}_{L_{Z_{0}}} \rightarrow  Z \times_{G/G_-} \mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{B}_-} \times \mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{B}_+} \times_{G_+\backslash G} Z \]
that induces a suitable symplectic form on $Z \times_{G/G_-} \mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{B}_-} \times \mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{B}_+} \times_{G_+\backslash G} Z$. We can proceed similarly to describe explicitly all the Morita equivalences in \eqref{eq:doumormodspa}. \end{proof}
\begin{remark} For future reference, let us point out that the Morita equivalence corresponding to $\mathfrak{M}_{L_{W}}(G)$ is, at the level of side groupoids, as follows: 
\begin{equation} \begin{tikzcd}
G_+ \ltimes (G/G_+) \arrow[d, shift right] \arrow[d, shift left] \arrow[r, dotted, bend left=49] & W\cong G \arrow[ld, "q_-"'] \arrow[rd, "q_+"] & (G_+\backslash G )\rtimes G_+\arrow[d, shift left] \arrow[d, shift right] \arrow[l, dotted, bend right=49] & {q_+(g)=G_+g} &   {q_-(g)=gG_+;} \\
 G/G_+                                                                                 &                                        & G_+\backslash G                                                                                            &                           &  &                   
\end{tikzcd}\end{equation}
with the actions given by left and right multiplication by $G_+$.
\end{remark}

\printbibliography
\end{document}


Thanks. But it is not 'strictly necessary'?

@cfr sometimes you really don't want the box from a minipage because you have a long paragraph that needs to page break for example, so it is possible to locally normalize the paragraph settings do the wrapfig and put them all back before the list environment notices but it starts to get..... fragile.

Is there an example somewhere? It would be useful to be able to use wrapfigure more, but they are typically most useful to me in or near lists or section headings. So, in practise, I only manage to use them rather rarely.

@cfr err I know I have disected wrapfig a few times, including merging it with lettrine once in an answer here but I'd have to search. basically I'm just saying it's only an interface to \parshape  so how hard can it be...... but these things are all relative and I don't have an example to hand:-)

Oh, thanks a lot for this!
